# JavaScript, This can enable a Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack

Tags: javascript, xss, sanitization

I have this code:

```
const implementation = async (req, res, next) => {
  const rut = req.user && req.user.nickname.toUpperCase();
  const data =  req.body; // ERROR !!!
  if (!rut || !data) res.send(400, {message: 'Error al recibir los datos'});
  let MetaData = await UserMetadata.findOneAndUpdate({rut}, {emergencyContact: data}, {new: true});
  if (!MetaData) res.send(400, {message: 'Ha ocurrido un error'});
  return res.send(200, MetaData);
};
```

Codegate is giving me a security error in the line 3:

> The application's async embeds untrusted data in the generated output with send, at line 3 of "my file". This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.
>
> The attacker would be able to alter the returned web page by simply providing modified data in the user input body, which is read by the async method at line 3 of "my file". This input then flows through the code straight to the output web page, without sanitization.
>
> This can enable a Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack.

How can avoid that security issue?

I tried with:

```
const data =  JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(req.body)));
```

The error disappear with `encodeURIComponent` functions but that doesn't have sense. Any hint?

EDIT: Full function now, the original one that has the error, and I must to "encode" or something to avoid the error.

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: What do you do with `data`?

Comment: not sure JSON would be an XSS target. I know most apps use validations to ensure the data is valid that is set in the body. Seems odd that cloning the object would not be secure.

Comment: It's should be an object that I append to a response. data should be an object

Comment: I have to ask... why are you encoding and then decoding it immediately? What's the point of that line? Why are you doing that instead of just `const data = req.body`?

Comment: Originally I was `const data = req.body` but that code wasn't being inspected by Codegate, now it is, and Codegate is giving me this errors. When I encode and decode it the error dissapear but I'm not sure why, I'm just trying-error the code...

Comment: How do you know it wasn't being inspected?

Comment: Becasue it wasn't, Codegate (the inspector) is a new feature on our Pipeline now, since 2 days. Before that we weren't inspecting the code (with similar tools like Sonarqube or something), it was a direct deploy.

Comment: It would help if you could post the full function or at least show what is done with `data`.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it right now

Comment: `const data =  req.body` followed by `await UserMetadata.findOneAndUpdate({rut}, {emergencyContact: data}, {new: true});` means that you are *directly* accepting user data and using it without any sanitisation or verification. User data *should always be treated as untrusted*. Data from the client is *always untrustworthy*. You then echo back the result of that operation to the user. So if the *untrusted data* you just inserted to your DB was bad, you return the same one back to the client. Whether that constitutes XSS will depend but it's definitely a danger.

Comment: @VLAZ Could you elaborate your comment based on my answer below? please, and thanks.

Comment: I don't know what Codegate checks for and how. I can only assume that it thinks you've handled the data safely after doing encode/decode and stringify/parse. Be aware that these tools are quite sophisticated to try and find potential issues but are also easily deceived, as they have a limit to their reasoning. Getting false positives and false negatives is not unheard of. It's not a constant occurrence but it does happen often enough so I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, I don't why but this works:

```
const implementation = async (req, res, next) => {
  const rut = req.user && req.user.nickname.toUpperCase();
  const data =  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  if (!rut || !data) res.send(400, {message: 'Error al recibir los datos'});
  let MetaData = await UserMetadata.findOneAndUpdate(
    {rut}, {emergencyContact: JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(data))}, {new: true}
  );
  if (!MetaData) res.send(400, {message: 'Ha ocurrido un error'});
  return res.send(200, MetaData);
};
```

Its kinda stupid to do and revert 2 things, the encodeURI and the stringify but Codegate now won't alert me for the error. I would love to know why was the error